# <Chrome App> How can I create a FileEntry without picking a file/directory from dialog?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, file-io, google-chrome-app

So far, I know I can get a fileEntry for read/write through `chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry`, but this will popup a fileManager to let user choose a file/directory.

What I want is I can give a path to `chooseEntry` or other way to create a fileEntry using code, not
a entry provided by fileManager Dialog.

```
var entry;
chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({type: 'openDirectory'}, function(fe){entry=fe;});
// This will call a file manager to let user select file which I want avoid
// instead I want to create a entry using a path string, like 'D:\test'
dirReader = entry.createReader()
dirReader.readEntries(function(r){
    console.log(r);
}, function(){console.error(' ')});
```

Comment: For security reasons, this is, to the best of my knowledge, impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Xan points out in a comment this is by design, for security reasons. We don't want apps to be able to open any file on your system they want, just the files the user has given the app access to.

If there is some particular task you are trying to do maybe ask a higher level question, as there is probably another option. E.g. if you want to have an options file somewhere which you provide the path to, you could use chrome.storage or the sandboxed file system.

Comment: Or `chrome.downloads` with a relative path works for some tasks.

Comment: Thanks. Guys. But the `storage` and `sanboxed file system` can't storage persistent on local machine as far as I know. Is there a way to do this? I will check `downloads` soon. @Xan

Comment: Yes! `storage` and `sanboxed file system` can storage data persistent! :-)